# Why are special characters replaced by ï¿½ in my Google Search results?

Tags: character-encoding, google-search

My website encoding is ISO-8859-1.
ISO-8859-1 is defined as charset in the web pages and Google Search results have always looked good.

However, for several weeks now, special characters (é, à, è, â, etc.) are replaced by ï¿½ in the Google Search results, for both page titles and page descriptions.

[Screenshot of the Google Search rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB8bi.jpg)

The charset is defined on each page: 
And the website looks good with all web browsers, there is no encoding errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have posted the question on Webmasters SE instead. Thanks.

Comment: It's a (double) [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. In Python: `'é, à, è, â'.encode( 'latin1').decode( 'utf-8', 'replace').encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')` returns `'ï¿½, ï¿½, ï¿½, ï¿½'`. Ask at https://superuser.com/ rather…